# Is there a way to export the develop setting of multiple photos and use them on another computer which has the same photos?

Tags: lightroom, storage, network, limited-space

I have a number of photos that need to be edited in Lightroom. I have 2 copies of each image (perfect copies, same filename) on 2 separate computers. I need to edit the photos on **computer A** in LR, and then move them to **computer B** (which also has LR installed) to perform further actions on them.

Exporting the edited photos and sending them from **computer A** to **computer B** is unfortunately not feasible because the size of the photos is very large. Uploading them would take so much time it would defeat the purpose, so I'm looking for an efficient way to transfer the custom develop setting but not the photos themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I copy my edits and metadata from the photos on my local drive to the same photos on my network drive?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/114971/how-can-i-copy-my-edits-and-metadata-from-the-photos-on-my-local-drive-to-the-sa)

Comment: I am curious as to why computer **A** can not do what computer **B** can do *"(which also has LR installed)"* and visa versa,  If the photo is already on **B** what can  **B** do that **A** can not ?  "*would take so much time it would defeat the purpose*" What  purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

For RAW files you ca set Lightroom to use side files (XMP) to store the edits.

Edit->Catalog Settings->Metadata and select "Automatically write changes into XMP"
[image]
Then you need to transfer those XMP files to Computer B in the same directories where are corresponding RAW file.

Unfortunately this work for all RAW files but not for DNG. Also it does not work for JPG,TIFF, PSD and PNG. For nonsupported files you should unselect the option above, do edits on computer A and transfer the entire catalog to computer B. Be aware Lightroom catalog can be between dozens of megabytes to few gigabytes. And the place of files on both computers should be the same to avoid a lot of hand work.